# Xamarin: Wrong certificate for bundle signing

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I'm having trouble with Xamarin and certificates.
I'm using VS 2019 16.11.5 Community Edition.

Whenever I try to deploy an app from VS to my iOS device I'm getting an error
Could not install the application 'C:\Users\thors\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\app2.iOS.app\out\app2.iOS.ipa' on the device iPhone Thowa. Details: ApplicationVerificationFailed(3892346901) - **Failed to verify code signature** of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.69Sye9/extracted/Payload/app2.iOS.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)

At the beginning of the build the logs shows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: app2.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
1> Detected signing identity:
1> Code Signing Key: "Apple Development: Thorsten W. (**7D8Lxxxxxx**)"
1> Provisioning Profile: "VS: WildCard Development"
```

But according to developer.apple.com my developer ID is Thorsten W. (**5KLMxxxxxx**)
I assume, this is the reason for not being able to verify the signing.

I XCode I'm seeing some certificate with a status "Not in Keychain"

I've tried already to remove all certificates from C:\Users\thors\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Certificates.
Also deleted the login data for Apple developer account in VS.
Nothing helps.

Any idea, why VS comes up with that developer ID?

Answer (score 1):

Using Hot Restart and Xcode and provisioning profiles is something that certainly won't work. I am not sure what was your intention but those things can't mix up as they don't work together at all.

Comment: ok, so what is your recomendation? Shall I disable Hot Restart? How can I do that? Or which other way shall I go?

Comment: @thowa honestly I have never used Hot Restart. But it definitely can't work in pair with XCode, one of its main purposes is to enable deployment from Windows directly to iOS device without the Mac.

Comment: I always thought, you need XCode in order to be able to compile for iOS. If I don't need XCode it is even better. But still I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I've just disconnected the MAC and I'm able to compile the app and it even  tries to deploy it to the iPhone. But still I' getting the error about "failed to verify the signature..."
Still VS uses the 7D8Lxxxxxx as Code signing key but unter Bundle Signing -> Automatic provisioning my Team id is different (5KLMxxxxxx)

Comment: Have you tried to use `Manual provisioning ` ?